# Can we use Spring-cloud-netflix and Hystrix to retry failed exectuion

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

I am using Spring-Cloud-netflix library.

I wonder if there is a way to take this code and add configure it instead of executing the fallback method right away to retry to execute it N times and in case of N times than execute the fallback method:

```
 @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "defaultInvokcation")
    public String getRemoteBro(String name) {
        return(executeRemoteService(name));
    }

     private String defaultInvokcation(String name) {
   return "something";
}
```

Thanks,
ray.

Comment: I don't think that this is job of hystrix. It's more your `executeRemoteService` who is responsible for the remote request behavior. Extend this method to "loop{success? return : try again} throw RequestAmountExceededException"

Comment: Ah. great idea. could please demonstrate this with an answer? I will mark it as answered. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482811/can-we-use-spring-cloud-netflix-and-hystrix-to-retry-failed-exectuion?noredirect=1#comment49046386_30482811):

Handle this behavior in your code. It's not the job of hystrix to know your "special" business logic. As an example

```
private final static int MAX_RETRIES = 5;

@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "defaultInvokcation")
public String getRemoteBro(String name) {
    return(executeRemoteService(name));
}

private String executeRemoteService(String serviceName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RETRIES; i++) {
        try {
            return reallyExecuteRemoteService(serviceName);
        } catch (ServiceException se) { 
          // handle or log execption
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("bam");
}
```

Don't know if you prefer to use an exception inside the loop ;) You could also wrap your answer from `reallyExecuteRemoteService`in some kind of ServiceReturnMessage with a status code.

Comment: Ahh I thought I can handle this within Hystrix exception handling. not my service exception

Comment: As I tried to express: Hystrix checks your service execution and if something fails it just fails from hystrix point of view. So the has to be logic in your called service. It will be really complex for hystrix to determine if a service (remote side) is dead or it just have to be asked again (just a thought: maybe based on the exception type from your call).

Comment: Well that would be nice if Hystrix could have a retry mechanism right before executing the default method (doesnt matter what was the fail reason)

Comment: If there would be a possibility you have to keep in mind that this will bring some more questions / configuration needs with it. Like the amount of retries or timeout between retry calls. On the other side: If your call does heavy work on the remote side (but ends with a exception) you will multiply the load on the remote server even if you can be sure that it will fail in every run. There is no mechanism to stop that before the circuit breaker gets active.

Comment: I hear you. Do you think you could "upgrade" your answer with the rxjava mode with hystrix concerned to that solution ? With subscribe.. coz I though that if I could subscribe to Oberservable within the exception I could decide what to do

Comment: Sorry but currently I don't have any rxjava projects running. I will improve the answer later.